# javascript how to initialized a async await function into a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

i am a beginner in javascript async await function. I have tried to make a asynchronous request in my backend and i want it to initialized in my variable but when I tried to log my variable, it gives me a promise and not a value. When i also tried to put an await. It gives me error.

Here is what I've done:

```
const getActivityContestApi = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${getDjangoApiHost()}/api/events/event_activity_contests/`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },          
         });
              
         const data = await response.json();               
         return data;
       } catch(error) {
          console.log(error)
      } 
    }
```

The function above is my asynchronous function, I want this to be stored in a variable like this:

```
const test_variable =  getActivityContestApi();
console.log(test_variable);
```

this code gives me a promise. I want the actual variable so I tried to put await like this:

```
const test_variable =  await getActivityContestApi();
console.log(test_variable);
```

this gives me error in react. please help.

Comment: `It gives me error.` `this gives me error in react.` What is the error?

Comment: Are you trying to call `getActivityContestApi()` in your render function?

Comment: await have to be used in a async function, so if you call await in a function without async you will get errror

Comment: here is the error Syntax error: 'await' is only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules

Comment: @tuannguyen yes thats the error

Comment: anyone help me with these? .  since I am a beginner in react

Comment: you have to call it in the async function. try this: var test_variable = null;
const fakeDate = async()=>{
    test_variable = await getActivityContestApi();
};
fakeDate();

Answer (score 1):

asyncFunction will return a promise. So if you just want get result, maybe you can use `then`

```
getActivityContestApi().then((resolve,reject)=>{
    let test_variable = resolve;
    console.log(test_variable);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

await is only allowed inside async function.

```
const test_variable =  await getActivityContestApi();
```

you can only use this statement inside another async function.

Answer (score 0):

`await` can't exist outside of `async` function. Here is what you need to do:

```
;(async () => {
    const test_variable = await getActivityContestApi();
    console.log(test_veriable);
})()
```